# Plotly - Add text outline or change color when text callout not visible?

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-python

I have the following code to create this chart in Plotly

[image]

```
fig = go.Figure()
fig = make_subplots(specs=[[{"secondary_y": True}]])

fig.add_trace(
    go.Bar(
        name         = "Registrazioni - Bank",
        marker_color = '#5B27A1', 
        x            = bnk_wk_cpa['Week'].dt.strftime('%d %b'),
        y            = bnk_wk_cpa['Registrazione - Bank'],
        text         = round(bnk_wk_cpa['Registrazione - Bank'],0),
        hoverinfo    = 'text',
        textposition = 'inside',
        width        = 0.65,
                            ),
     secondary_y  = False
)

fig.add_trace(
    go.Scatter(
        name         = 'CPA',
        marker_color = '#FD009D', 
        x            = bnk_wk_cpa['Week'].dt.strftime('%d %b'),
        y            = bnk_wk_cpa['CPA - Bank'],
        text         = round(bnk_wk_cpa['CPA - Bank'],2),
        line         = dict(
#        shape        = 'spline',
        width        = 3.5),
        mode         = 'lines+markers+text',
        hoverinfo    = 'text',
        textposition = 'top center'),
    secondary_y  = True
)


fig.add_trace(
    go.Bar(
        name         = "Spend",
        marker_color = '#321461', 
        x            = bnk_wk_cpa['Week'].dt.strftime('%d %b'),
        y            = np.full(len(bnk_wk_cpa), 1),
        text         = round(bnk_wk_cpa['Spend - Bank'],1),
        hoverinfo    = 'text',
        textposition = 'inside',
        textfont     = dict(
        size         = 25),
        width        = 0.65,
        yaxis        = "y3",
                            ),
)


fig.update_traces(texttemplate='%{text:.2s}')

fig.update_layout(
    showlegend          = True,
    paper_bgcolor       = "rgba(0,0,0,0)",
    plot_bgcolor        = "rgba(0,0,0,0)",
    margin              = dict(
    t                   = 30,
   # l                   = 10,
   # b                   = 10,
   # r                   = 10
    ),
    font_color          = '#000',
    font_family         = 'Trebuchet MS',
    font_size           = 24,
    width               = 1633, 
    height              = 750,
    legend              = dict(
    yanchor             = "top",
    y                   = 1.13,
    xanchor             = "left",
    x                   = 0.015,
    title               = '',
    orientation         = 'h',
    ))


fig.update_yaxes(visible=False)

fig.update_layout(
    yaxis={
        "domain": [0, 0.88],
    },
    yaxis2={
        "domain": [0, 0.88],
    },
    yaxis3={"domain": [0.92, 0.98], "visible": False},
)

fig.update_traces(hovertemplate=None)
fig.update_layout(hovermode="x unified")

fig.show()
```

I would like to make the callout text of the CPA line visible at all times. I was wondering whether it was possible to:

**A.** Change color of the text when it enters the bar graph

**B.** Add a text stroke of white around the text so that its' always visible (see picture below done with Google Sheets)

[image]

**C.** Maybe plot the line graph between the two charts so that the call out data is always visible - this would mean making the line chart's height smaller I imagine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as you didnt add the data to recreate the grap I will give you the option of how to do this

for a
you can control that text color using the textfont parameter in the  go.Scatter function

you have 2 option
1- set 1 color to all text this is done as following

```
fig.add_trace(
    go.Scatter(
        name         = 'CPA',
        marker_color = '#FD009D', 
        x            = bnk_wk_cpa['Week'].dt.strftime('%d %b'),
        y            = bnk_wk_cpa['CPA - Bank'],
        text         = round(bnk_wk_cpa['CPA - Bank'],2),
        line         = dict(
#        shape        = 'spline',
        width        = 3.5),
        mode         = 'lines+markers+text',
        hoverinfo    = 'text',
        textfont=dict(
            color="magenta",
            
    )
        textposition = 'top center'),
    secondary_y  = True
)
```

or you can pass a list of color value base on positon instead

```
 textfont={
        "color": ["MidnightBlue", "IndianRed", "MediumPurple", "Gold", "Crimson",
                  "LightSeaGreen",
                  "RoyalBlue", "LightSalmon", "DarkOrange", "MediumSlateBlue"],
        "family": ["Arial, sans-serif", "Balto, sans-serif", "Courier New, monospace",
                   "Droid Sans, sans-serif", "Droid Serif, serif",
                   "Droid Sans Mono, sans-serif",
                   "Gravitas One, cursive", "Old Standard TT, serif",
                   "Open Sans, sans-serif",
                   "PT Sans Narrow, sans-serif", "Raleway, sans-serif",
                   "Times New Roman, Times, serif"],
        "size": [22, 21, 20, 19, 18, 17, 16, 15, 14, 13]
    }
```

for border, you will need to add them as annotation

see plotly examples here https://plotly.com/python/text-and-annotations/